# Adding padding beneath button and within radio section

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to modify this code so that the actions button has a little padding that does not highlight on hover below the button.

I was trying to use my `action-blank` class by sandwiching the button between 2 blank lines but the blank lines were getting highlighted.

**Ideally, the ACTIONS button is present on all sections without needing to click them to appear**

```css
.vertical-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.trend-button:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 2.5%, #f0f0f0 2.5%, #f0f0f0 97.5%, transparent 97.5%);
  align-items: center;
}


/* Exclude blank line and blank element from hover effect */

.button-label-line>div:hover,
.actions-container>.action-blank {
  background: none;
}


/* Style for the blank element */

.action-blank {
  height: 0.5em;
  /* Adjust height as needed */
}

.button-label-divider {
  height: 5px;
}

.actions-container>.action-blank {
  background: none;
}


/* Style for the blank element */

.action-blank {
  height: 0.5em;
  /* Adjust height as needed */
}

.vertical-menu input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

.vertical-menu label {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.vertical-menu label:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.vertical-menu input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.vertical-menu .trend-button {
  display: none;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}

.vertical-menu input[type="radio"]:checked+label+.trend-button {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Adjust the margin to remove white space */
}

.vertical-menu input[type="radio"]:checked+label+.trend-button button {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-menu" id="menu">
  <input type="radio" id="option1" name="menu-option" checked>
  <label for="option1">#H1#<div class="subtitle">#S1#</div></label>
  <div class="trend-button">
    #ACTIONS#
  </div>

  <input type="radio" id="option2" name="menu-option">
  <label for="option2">#H2#<div class="subtitle">#S2#</div></label>
  <div class="trend-button">
    #ACTIONS#
  </div>

  <input type="radio" id="option3" name="menu-option">
  <label for="option3">#H3#<div class="subtitle">#S3#</div></label>
  <div class="trend-button">
    #ACTIONS#
  </div>

  <input type="radio" id="option4" name="menu-option">
  <label for="option4">#H4#<div class="subtitle">#S4#</div></label>
  <div class="trend-button">
    #ACTIONS#
  </div>
</div>
```

For context something like this

When one section is selected:
[image]
When hovering on button:
[image]

Comment: I highly recommend you reread what you wrote as it doesnt make an sense & would require too much energy to understand it. As a side note, I was not the one who downvoted you.

Comment: I reckon adding margins around your buttons would do the trick.

Comment: @twalow I updated it. Spent more time on mockup. Lmk if its more clear.

Comment: I apologize @fatpenguin do you mind just pointing out where. I'm new to this.

Comment: Say, add a "margin: 0.5rem 0 0.5rem 0;" inside the CSS styling of your buttons. That would leave a 0.5rem space above and below the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the `bottom` property for more space below the button.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

const qs = (el) => document.querySelector(el);
const qsAll = (el) => document.querySelectorAll(el);

qsAll(".section").forEach(($section) => {
  $section.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    qs(".section.selected").classList.remove("selected");
    e.target.closest('.section').classList.add("selected");
  });
});


});
```

```css
.section {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.section:hover {
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.section:hover button.actions {
  background: #eee;
}

.section.selected {
  background: #04AA6D;
}

button.actions {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
}

button.actions:hover {
  background: #fff !important;
}



.section.selected button.actions {
  background: #04AA6D;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section relative selected">
    <div class="">#H1#</div>
    <div class="">#S1#</div>
    <button class="actions">#ACTIONS#</button>
  </div>
   <div class="section relative">
    <div class="">#H2#</div>
    <div class="">#S2#</div>
    <button class="actions">#ACTIONS#</button>
  </div>
   <div class="section relative">
    <div class="">#H3#</div>
    <div class="">#S3#</div>
    <button class="actions">#ACTIONS#</button>
  </div>
   <div class="section relative">
    <div class="">#H4#</div>
    <div class="">#S4#</div>
    <button class="actions">#ACTIONS#</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time. Unfortunately for this specific case I need to stick to using radio buttons.

Comment: Just switch out divs to radio buttons. The point of the concept shows you have to do with with css.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some modifications to your code. Perhaps these changes could be beneficial for you. You can find the updated code here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/moSic3xHZM.